# Adding ArcGIS Rest Service Tools/Special Features to ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

[Adding from the ArcGIS Services Directory](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-arcgis-server-map-services.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_78FC8E5DBF1D4E04945656AEFDA40E06) shows how to add ArcGIS Rest Service Map Layers to ArcGIS Desktop.  However, it does not mention adding tools/Special Services.  I am attempting to add the [GetLatLon](https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer/exts/CadastralSpecialServices/GetLatLon) service from BLM to my ArcGIS Desktop program but cannot figure it out.  I've attempted to add a Tool, and navigate to the server https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ but no tools are available.

How do I add ArcGIS Rest Service Tools/Special Features to ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not able to see any geoprocessing services tools is because the `GetLatLon` end point you refer to is an extension of a map service. Most likely, it is a [Server Object Extension (SOE)](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/about-extending-services.htm). If you scroll down to the end of the MapServer metadata page (https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer), you will see the `CadastralSpecialServices` under the `Supported Extensions:` section.

You will not be able to access this extension in ArcMap as you need to access this extension programmatically. You can look at the documentation on [ArcGIS REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/get-started-with-the-services-directory.htm) and if you get serious, at some examples on [Server object extension usage in client applications](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/server-object-extension-usage-in-client-applications.htm).

Comment: I ended up building a list of 176 URLs (max character limit for URLs required multiple) and using wget with a text list input nad push the output to a text file, which I then parsed with sed.  So, I was able to get the lat/lon for over 3000 PLSS descriptions rather quickly that way.

Comment: ...Or you could just use Python `requests` package to make it easier for you :) you could try and then if you get stuck, post a question!